# How to test write to file with rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, stub

I have my function code like this :

```
      Dir.mkdir('config') unless File.exist?('config')
      File.open('config/brakeman.yml', 'wb') do |file|
        file.write(response.body)
```

How can I test the line which is file.write(response.body)?
I tried to mock and stub like this:

```
  allow(response).to receive(:body).and_return(body)
  allow(File).to receive(:open).with('config/brakeman.yml', 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(response.body)
  end
  expect(File).to receive(:open).with('config/brakeman.yml', 'wb')
  subject.create_config(response)
  expect(file).to receive(:write).with(body)
  expect(File.open('config/brakeman.yml')).to eq(body)
```

Comment: What you get when you run your test?

Comment: What is the purpose of getting that line tested? `IO#write` is implemented in the standard library, so I wouldn’t feel a particular need to test it. Is it simply in order to increase test coverage?

Comment: You might want to use the [fakefs](https://github.com/fakefs/fakefs) gem to stub out the file system if this is a critical test. Writing to the actual file system can cause all kinds of issues with test idempotency and mocking extensively like this will cause a test that will break if the code is refactored. You should test what the code does - not how it does the job.

Comment: Yes I wanted this line to be covered mainly for test coverage, but Amir is right. We should  not test the func that are already tested, instead we should focus on the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not a good idea to test standard library methods. Just cover it with

```rb
allow(File).to receive(:open).with('config/brakeman.yml', 'wb') do |file|
  expect(file).to receive(:write).with(response.body)
end
```

And that should be enough, I think

Do not test code that already tested :)

Comment: I used and_yield instead. But right, Do not test code that already tested.